# Why is $\mathbf r(t) \times \mathbf r'(t)$ constant, with $\mathbf r(t): \mathbb R\to\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cross-product

Let $\mathbf r(t): \mathbb R\to\mathbb R^3$ be a funtion of time representing a point subject to a radial acceleration, i.e. $\mathbf r''(t)$ is parallel to $\mathbf r(t)$. Prove that $\mathbf r(t) \times \mathbf r'(t) = \mathbf h$ (where $\times$ is the cross product), with $\mathbf h$ constant and that the trajectory is in a plane perpendicular to $\mathbf h$.

How should I prove this? (There is no initial position or velocity).

I'm posting this problem on math stack exchange because it is on my math book and i'm not even supposed to take a course in physics

Comment: It's the cross product, i'll add that to the question

Comment: Are you sure the acceleration is *parallel* to the position? Shouldn't it instead be perpendicular? Because otherwise the cross-product is zero, and from the situation it seems that it should be perpendicular

Comment: That is my first concern. My book is very clear  about it and it's parallel. I suppose that since 0 (the vector) is also constant, and every plane is perpendicular to 0, the problem is trivially solved. Maybe, with an initial velocity different from 0, the point won't simply go straight (if I understood correctly)

Comment: Since the next problem is about proving kepler equation, I suppose that this one is about a point in space (maybe a planet) subject to a central force

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not to show that $\mathbf r(t) \times \mathbf r'(t) = \mathbf h$? This would make more sense in the context and would lead to the trajectory being in a plane.

Comment: You are right, it is. I don't know how I didn't notice before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbf r $ and $\mathbf r'' $ are parallel, we have (by properties of the cross product) that:

$$\mathbf r \times \mathbf r'' = \mathbf 0$$

Also, trivially

$$\mathbf r' \times \mathbf r' = \mathbf 0$$

Hence

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf 0 &= \mathbf r' \times \mathbf r' + \mathbf r \times \mathbf r''
\\ &=  \frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf r \times \mathbf r')
\end{align}$$

Which implies that

$$\mathbf r \times \mathbf r'= \mathbf h$$

where $\mathbf h$ is a constant vector. Take the dot product with $\mathbf r$ to give

$$ \mathbf r \cdot \mathbf h = \mathbf r \cdot(\mathbf r \times \mathbf r') = \mathbf 0 $$

and $\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf h = \mathbf 0$ is the equation of a plane through the origin, perpendicular to $\mathbf h$ .

Answer (score 1):

Define $h(t) = r(t)\times r'(t)$. Differentiate $h'(t) = r'(t)\times r'(t) +r(t)\times r''(t) = 0 + 0$ to argue that $h(t)$ is constant. Now, argue that $r(t)\times h$ is always zero.